# PCA9956A How to set AIF bit

Tags: datasheet, led-driver, flag

I am using the https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCA9956A.pdf chip to control LEDs.

To set the autoincrement mode three beets are needed,

[image]

[image]

But the **`AIF`** bit is marked as read-only.

Is it a mistake or there is another way of changing it but I am not smart enough to find it in the datasheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AIF bit is sent as MSB of the register address you want to access. Therefore current status is read only and can't be set via MODE1 register. It is described right above Table 6 you posted.

Comment: Sa the post sentence is true :)